# Merging custom doubly linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have two custom made doubly linked list and a method insertAt(int pos,DoublyLinkedList l) that should insert the list l before the given index of the other list. However, after using it, nothing happens, even though when I watch the proccess in debugger everything seems to go fine. Program compiles, it just does not give any result. Here's the minimal example:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList{
private static final class Node {

    protected Object data;

    protected Node next, prev;

    /* Constructor */
    public Node() {

        next = null;

        prev = null;

        data = 0;

    }

    /* Constructor */
    public Node(Object d, Node n, Node p) {

        data = d;

        next = n;

        prev = p;

    }

    /* Function to set link to next node */
    public void setLinkNext(Node n) {

        next = n;

    }

    /* Function to set link to previous node */
    public void setLinkPrev(Node p) {

        prev = p;

    }

    /* Funtion to get link to next node */
    public Node getLinkNext() {

        return next;

    }

    /* Function to get link to previous node */
    public Node getLinkPrev() {

        return prev;

    }

    /* Function to set data to node */
    public void setData(Object d) {

        data = d;

    }

    /* Function to get data from node */
    public Object getData() {

        return data;

    }

}
protected Node start;

protected Node end;

public int size;

/* Constructor */
public DoublyLinkedList() {

    start = null;

    end = null;

    size = 0;

}
public void insertBefore(int pos, DoublyLinkedList l) {


    Node ptr = start;
    if (pos == 1) {
        l.end.setLinkNext(start);
        start.setLinkPrev(l.end);
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++) {
           if(i==pos){

               ptr.setLinkPrev(l.end);
               l.end.setLinkNext(ptr);

               Node tmp=ptr;
               ptr = ptr.getLinkPrev();
               ptr.setLinkNext(l.start);
               l.start.setLinkNext(tmp);

               size=size()+l.size();
               break;
           }
            ptr=ptr.getLinkNext();
        }

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    DoublyLinkedList list1 = new DoublyLinkedList();
    list1.insertAtEnd("a");
    list1.insertAtEnd("b");
    list1.insertAtEnd("c");
    list1.insertAtEnd("d");
    list1.insertAtEnd("e");

     DoublyLinkedList list2 = new DoublyLinkedList();
    list2.insertAtEnd("1");
    list2.insertAtEnd("2");
    list2.insertAtEnd("3");
    list2.insertAtEnd("4");
    list2.insertAtEnd("5");

    list1.display();
    list2.display();

    list1.insertBefore(3, list2);
    list1.display();
    list1.size();
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
           ptr.setLinkPrev(l.end);
           l.end.setLinkNext(ptr);

           Node tmp=ptr;
           ptr = ptr.getLinkPrev();
           ptr.setLinkNext(l.start);
           l.start.setLinkNext(tmp);
```

1. it sets the end of the new list as `ptr`'s predecessor, and links it back properly.
2. a temporary variable keeps the current reference to ptr.
3. Then you move `ptr` to refer to its predecessor. But this predecessor is not what used to be `ptr`'s predecessor in the original list. It's the result of step (1) above, the end item of the new list!
4. Then you tell this item, the end of the new list, to link to the new list's beginning... The new list will now become a circle. But only singly-linked.
5. Then you link the start's `next` to what you saved - the old `ptr`.

As a result your forward links from the old start still go the old way - they have not changed much. But the back links are broken, and the new list's links are broken.

You *think* nothing changed because your printing method probably just walks the list through its forward links. Try to write another printing method that walks them backwards, it should become interesting...

One way to solve this would be to save `ptr`'s predecessor before you replace it, and use that for forward-linking the new list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
ptr.setLinkPrev(l.end);
l.end.setLinkNext(ptr);

Node tmp=ptr;
ptr = ptr.getLinkPrev();

//ptr is now the last node of l, not the previous node of original list!!!

//==> you cycle your l list again in the next instruction:
ptr.setLinkNext(l.start);
l.start.setLinkNext(tmp);

size=size()+l.size();
break;
```

You should save the previous node of ptr BEFORE you start merging...

It should be:

```
Node tmp = prev.getLinkPrev();
ptr.setLinkPrev(l.end);
l.end.setLinkNext(ptr);

tmp.setLinkNext(l.start);
l.start.setLinkPrev(tmp);
size=size()+l.size();
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with help of your hint guys, thanks.

```
public void insertBefore(int pos, DoublyLinkedList l) {
    checkOutOfBounds(pos);

    Node ptr = start;
    if (pos == 1) {
        l.end.setLinkNext(start);
        start.setLinkPrev(l.end);
        start=l.start;
        size=size()+l.size();
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= size; i++) {
           if(i==pos){
               Node tmp=ptr;
               ptr.setLinkPrev(l.end);
               l.end.setLinkNext(ptr.getLinkNext());


               tmp.setLinkNext(l.start);
               l.start.setLinkPrev(tmp);

               size=size()+l.size();
               break;
           }
            ptr=ptr.getLinkNext();
        }

    }

}
```